# Module 'numpy' has no attribute 'collections', plotting a decision tree

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, data-visualization, decision-tree

I have a numpy array of dimension (81,38) as a training data features, and another list of length 82 as the labels.

I trained my DecisionTreeClassifier using them, and I want to visualize the tree, but the following error appeared:

```
edges = np.collections.defaultdict(list)
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'collections'
```

this is my code:

```
from sklearn import tree
df = df.from_csv("file_path.csv")
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
df = df.as_matrix()
print(df.shape)
print(len(train_df['label'].values.tolist()))
clf = clf.fit(df,train_df['label'].values.tolist())

data_feature_names = [ 'goEmbed1', 'goalexa1', 'goscapy1',
                       'goEmbed2', 'goalexa2', 'goscapy2',
                       'goEmbed3', 'goalexa3', 'goscapy3',
                       'goEmbed4', 'goalexa4', 'goscapy4',
                       'goEmbed5', 'goalexa5', 'goscapy5',
                       'goStdAlex', 'goAvgAlexa', 'goStdCos','goAvgCos',

                       'bingEmbed1', 'bingalexa1', 'bingscapy1',
                       'bingEmbed2', 'bingalexa2', 'bingscapy2',
                       'bingEmbed3', 'bingalexa3', 'bingscapy3',
                       'bingEmbed4', 'bingalexa4', 'bingscapy4',
                       'bingEmbed5', 'bingalexa5', 'bingscapy5',
                       'bingStdAlex', 'bingAvgAlexa', 'bingStdCos','bingAvgCos']

# Visualize data
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf,
                                feature_names=data_feature_names,
                                out_file=None,
                                filled=True,
                                rounded=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)

colors = ('turquoise', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow','blue','purple')
edges = np.collections.defaultdict(list)

for edge in graph.get_edge_list():
    edges[edge.get_source()].append(int(edge.get_destination()))

for edge in edges:
    edges[edge].sort()
    for i in range(2):
        dest = graph.get_node(str(edges[edge][i]))[0]
        dest.set_fillcolor(colors[i])

graph.write_png('tree2.png')
```

I tested my code on another example of data, and It works perfectly, but I don't know that is the problem here.

This is the testing data that I used:

```
X = [ [180, 15,0],
      [177, 42,0],
      [136, 35,1],
      [174, 65,0],
      [141, 28,1]]

Y = ['man', 'woman', 'woman', 'man', 'woman']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because numpy has no collections... make it like

```
import collections
edges = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Answer (score -1):

Numpy doesn't have an attribute called 'collections' because collections is a different package.
However please change your code to :

```
import collections
edges = collections.defaultdict(list)
```